# UIScrollView Item not moving from the background

Tags: swift, uiscrollview, autolayout, swift4, snapkit

I setup my constraints so that I would have a chart that takes up the screen when you load in, but you are able to scroll down to see more information. However, I can see the scroll bar moving, and the chart does not move!

```
var scrollView: UIScrollView {
    let scroll = UIScrollView()
    self.view.addSubview(scroll)
    scroll.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
        make.edges.equalTo(self.view)
    }
    return scroll

}
var contentView: UIView {
    let content = UIView()
    self.scrollView.addSubview(content)
    content.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
        make.top.bottom.equalTo(self.scrollView)
        make.left.right.equalTo(self.view)
        make.width.equalTo(self.scrollView)
    }
    // self.scrollView.contentSize = content.frame.size
    return content
}
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.contentView.addSubview(self.chart)

    self.chart.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
        // http://snapkit.io/docs/
        // https://github.com/SnapKit/SnapKit/issues/448
        make.top.equalTo(self.contentView)
        make.left.right.equalTo(self.contentView)
        make.height.equalTo(self.view).offset(-(self.tabBarController?.tabBar.frame.height)!)
    }
    self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: self.view.frame.width, height: 3000) // Testing

}
```

So the scroll bar moves, but the content is not.
[image]

Comment: could you post a screenshot or a small video of what is not really working?

Comment: @CatalinaT. Fixed

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, you're doing a number of things wrong.

First, when you use this construct:

```
var scrollView: UIScrollView {
    let scroll = UIScrollView()
    self.view.addSubview(scroll)
    scroll.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
        make.edges.equalTo(self.view)
    }
    return scroll
}
```

***Every time*** you refer to `scrollView` you are creating ***another*** instance of the scroll view. Running your code, and using Debug View Hierarchy, this is what you get:

[image]

The `red` views are scrollViews and the `blue` views are contentViews. As you can see, that's definitely *not* what you want.

Here is an example of how you can do what you're trying to do:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var scrollView: UIScrollView = {
        let scroll = UIScrollView()
        scroll.backgroundColor = .red
        return scroll

    }()

    var contentView: UIView  = {
        let content = UIView()
        content.backgroundColor = .blue
        return content
    }()

    var chart: UILabel = {
        let v = UILabel()
        v.numberOfLines = 0
        v.text = "This is the\nChart View"
        v.backgroundColor = .cyan
        v.textAlignment = .center
        return v
    }()

    var bottomLabel: UILabel = {
        let v = UILabel()
        v.text = "The Bottom Label"
        v.backgroundColor = .yellow
        v.textAlignment = .center
        return v
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // add scrollView
        self.view.addSubview(scrollView)

        // constrain to safe area (so it doesn't extend below the tab bar)
        scrollView.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
            make.edges.equalTo(self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide)
        }

        // add contentView to scrollView
        self.scrollView.addSubview(contentView)

        // constrain all 4 edges to scrollView
        // this will allow auto-layout to control / define the .contentSize
        contentView.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
            make.edges.equalTo(self.scrollView)
        }

        // constrain contentView's width to scrollView's width
        // but we *don't* constrain its height
        contentView.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
            make.width.equalTo(self.scrollView)
        }

        // add the chart to contentView
        self.contentView.addSubview(self.chart)

        // constrain chart to top, left and right of contentView
        // constrain its height to scrollView's height (so it initially fills the visible area
        chart.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
            make.top.equalTo(self.contentView)
            make.left.right.equalTo(self.contentView)
            make.height.equalTo(self.scrollView)
        }

        // now, we'll add a label to scrollView
        self.contentView.addSubview(self.bottomLabel)

        // constrain the label left and right with 20-pts, and a height of 40
        bottomLabel.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
            make.left.equalTo(self.contentView).offset(20)
            make.right.equalTo(self.contentView).offset(-20)
            make.height.equalTo(40)
        }

        // constrain the label's TOP 20-pts below the BOTTOM of chart view
        bottomLabel.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
            make.top.equalTo(self.chart.snp.bottom).offset(20)
        }

        // constrain the BOTTOM of the label 20-pts from the bottom of contentView
        bottomLabel.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
            make.bottom.equalTo(self.contentView).offset(-20)
        }

        // with those constraints, contentView's height is now:
        // chart's height + 20 + label's height + 20
        // and because contentView's bottom is constrained to scrollView's bottom,
        // that becomes scrollView's contentSize

    }

}
```

I added a `UILabel` as the `chart` view, and another label below it to show how to use auto-layout to define the scroll content.

Initial view:

[image]

Scrolled up:

[image]

and, the resulting View Hierarchy:

[image]

The comments I've included in the code should clarify how and why it's done this way.

Comment: Awesome answer! Thank you so much.

Comment: Tip: you can combine all the constraints into one make loop.

Comment: Yes, you can combine them. However, particularly when just learning, it can be helpful to separate things out (along with clear comments) to make it easier to understand what we're doing and why.

Comment: why do you need both a top and bottom constraint? Why can't I just include a top one and the height. I tried this and it did not work.

Comment: Which ones specifically?

Comment: the `bottomLabel`.

Comment: With auto-layout constraints, you can tell a "containing view" to size its subviews, or you can tell it to get ***its size*** from its subviews. In the case of your `contentView`, you want its subviews to determine its height. That way you can add any subviews you want, and as long as you have a clean "top-to-bottom chain" of constraints, it will automatically set the height. With the contentView constrained properly to the scroll view, you automatically get proper scrolling (never any need to explicitly set `.contentSize`).